# Can I override die globally in my perl project from my invoking script?

Tags: perl, perl-module

I am writing a perl application in Windows where I am using an invoking perl script and there are several hierarchical perl oo modules. I want to customize the way perl handles die. 
I know of using $SIG{**DIE**} and use "use subs die" but can I put it into my invoking script only and expect that now, if any of the module in my application will go through this handler only?

I have tried something like this but didn't work:

```
$SIG{__DIE__} = \&_death_handler;
use Mypackage;

my $obj = Mypackage->new();
$obj->init;


sub _die_handler {
    print "I die handler\n";
}
```

Mypackage looks something like this:

```
package Mypackage;

sub new {
   .....
   .....
}

sub init {
    my $self = shift;
    die "error\n";
}
```

This seems to work only when I am calling die from the invoking script, but the die called from Mypackage is not getting handled by the handler.

Comment: @ikegami, the issue the OP is facing, I think, is that the `__DIE__` handler is a reference to a typo'd subroutine...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible: "if you really need to catch calls to die, you can define CORE::GLOBAL::die"

http://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2011/05/override-die-with-end-or-coreglobaldie/

Comment: Can't I put the CORE::GLOBAL::die handler outside BEGIN. I am trying to integrate the die error messages to my Log4perl log files. So if I put it in BEGIN and initialize the handlers, the log files are getting created every time my ide uses run time checking for sytax errors.

Answer (score 2):

Typo, unfortunately not one caught by `strict` nor `warnings`;

You have assigned a reference to the *undefined* subroutine `_death_handler` when you meant to reference the subroutine you did define, `_die_handler`.

Correct the typo and enjoy the message "I die handler" (from your sub `_die_handler`).